# php div overlaps with footer

Tags: php, html, css

Can anyone help me out? I'm trying to figure out why 2 `div`s overlap each other.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXVDC.png)

This is how it looks and I can't get the footer beneath the body which is the white box.

My body code is:

```
<body style = 'background-image: url("/images/sitebg.jpg")'>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="mainmenu">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Recipes</a>
            <a href="#">Gameplay Footage</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main" class="site-main">

</div>
<div>
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS for the footer is:

```
.site-footer {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        padding: 3.5em;
    }

    c {color:black;font-family:"Agency FB";font-size:16px; position: relative;}
    lo1 {color:black;font-family:"Agency FB";font-size:22px;text-shadow: 2px 2px Orange;text-align:"center";}
    .site-main {

    margin-bottom: 0px;

}

    .mainmenu {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;

}
```

footer code is:

```
        </div>
    <div class="site-footer"
        <center><div><c>Powered by</c> <lo1><a href="" target="_blank">Phoenix78</lo1> <c>2017 ©</c></div></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

header code is:

```
    <html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
<body class="body">
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <center><h1></h1>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

after changing the code as suggested the design was mixed and i got the following:
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ArC.png)

but i guess it can be fixed by css adjustment

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

[image: current look]

Comment: what do you mean by "overlaps" ? what do you expect the output should be ?

Comment: PHP generates the HTML. PHP isn't overlapping. Post the generated source.

Comment: my goal is to stack the footer underneath the body

Comment: im sorry for the noob question but please explain generated source ?

Comment: I just wonder if the `div` with the `class="site-footer"` is output by the PHP file. In any case I'd also like to see the CSS for `.mainmenu` and `.site-main`. This is all HTML/CSS, it has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: And @chris85 means that we need to see whatever those `include` functions are actually returning, in other words, what's the final HTML shown when you load the site.

Comment: thank you for the patience :)

Comment: Well look at `<div class="site-footer" <center>`. Also that goes in the question not as comments. Also what is a `c` and `lo1` elements, new HTML5 ? Use http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15635569.

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting it all on the comments! But we get the idea now.

Comment: Also if `footer.php` has `</body> </html>` you are closing your `body` twice. Your header also closes the body. I recommend an HTML tutorial. This is all over the place.

Comment: Well, the issue is very clear... I'll try to post an answer but Chris is right, you need to learn more about HTML and ultimately PHP on the way.

Comment: im sorry for the mess
so learnin html through using php isn't the best choice?

Comment: I'm fairly certain your HTML is malformed. For instance, if your body code includes your header code, then your actual HTML document is defined after your body tag -- your first body tag because, the way your code is written above, your page will have 2 body tags.

Comment: They are entirely separate languages. Your PHP actually looks better than your HTML. The HTML has numerous issues. Your `header.php` is (would be) a full HTML file. You should have 1 `head`, and 1 `body` element. The `head` contains meta information and resources that are needed. The `body` should contain the content of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

center is not closed properly
also, is deprecated, and should be avoided

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
**<body class="body">**
<header>
    <div class="container">
        **<center>**<h1></h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Also, your code puts two body tags on the document

Comment: it was but that wasn't my issue

Answer (score 0):

So based upon the comments, your main HTML file should contain:

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body style = 'background-image: url("/images/sitebg.jpg")'>
<div class="mainmenu">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Recipes</a>
            <a href="#">Gameplay Footage</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main" class="site-main">

</div>
<div class="site-footer">
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your `header.php` file should **only output** the following HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Title</title>
```

Your `footer.php` file should **only output** the following HTML:

```
<span class="c">Powered by</span> <span class="lo1"><a href="" target="_blank">Phoenix78</a></span> <span class="c">2017 ©</span>
```

But, of course, these last two are completely unnecessary if you're not loading stuff dynamically, therefore you should consider just copying the HTML inside your main file instead of loading files.

This means that your best option is to simply do this:

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style = 'background-image: url("/images/sitebg.jpg")'>
<div class="mainmenu">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Recipes</a>
            <a href="#">Gameplay Footage</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main" class="site-main">

</div>
<div class="site-footer">
    <span class="c">Powered by</span> <span class="lo1"><a href="" target="_blank">Phoenix78</a></span> <span class="c">2017 ©</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If that doesn't solve anything, then we need to proceed with more CSS modifications, but as far as this goes, that should fix any HTML problem.

Note: `<c>` and `<lo1>` are not HTML tags (or at least I've never heard of them). Use classes if you need to stylize these elements.

**EDIT**

Here is the CSS modification needed to bring back the style of your original HTML/CSS work:

```
.site-footer {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 3.5em;
}

.c {
    color: black;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

.lo1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    font-size: 22px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px Orange;
    text-align: center;
}

.site-main {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mainmenu {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: c and lo1 is css classes i tried putting it in <> and it took the css design even though you don't write code this way im not familiar with php and it worked so i left it
the output is partially code after using the index.php you suggested

Comment: I'll add the code you need to update in your CSS to bring back the style then.

Comment: thank you so much! p.s i have added a screenshot for current look

Comment: I see, I just looked at the result. I just added the CSS needed, note that the only thing I did was to add `text-align: center;` to the `.site-footer` class and then I added a `.` before `c` and `lo1` to turn them into class selectors. That should fix it. Of course, I did **not** analyze it yet, so it might still overlap, but once I figure out what is what on the screenshots, then I'll check on that.

Comment: there's a progress but still positioning is not there yet the footer and the body still side by side instead of footer beneath the body thanks again i learned allot thanks to you guys advises

Comment: Ok great, show me again how it looks so far and please tell me what element (tag) is the box because I can't tell by the CSS I have right now. I'll try to figure out why it's not positioning well (I have an idea already) if you do that. And you're welcome!

Comment: attached i worked on it and got the header and header menu in perfect position but the body is stuck there and i cant put some empty space between the menu and the body

Comment: finally solved it 
in site-main class i had position: absolute; once i changed it i could move the body part away from the header

i wanna thank you both chris35 and Zeke for all the patience and teaching  thank you from the bottom of my heart

Comment: Oh I see, so there was more to it than I thought, I was getting worried because I couldn't tell what `<div>` was the white box, if I had known that earlier I'd probably would've figured it out yesterday. Well I'm glad it's working, and you're welcome!

Comment: @ChenZen let me be curious, what made you change your decision? (I don't mind, but since it's been almost a year...)